# How to visualize the kernels in Conv1D layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I was reading this article about Conv1d. https://xzz201920.medium.com/conv1d-conv2d-and-conv3d-8a59182c4d6
It says that the kernel size automatically turns into 2 dimension matrix. For example, if the kernel size is 5 and the input channels\data points is 12 then internally tensorflow\keras would change the kernel shape to (5,12) and then basically perform convolution 2d.So to test this theory I tried it out myself with this code:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers import Convolution1D
import numpy as np
K.clear_session()
toy = Sequential([
 Convolution1D(filters=1, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='valid', use_bias=False, input_shape=(5000,12), name='c1d')
])
toy.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=5e-2), loss='mae')
values=toy.layers[0].get_weights()
print(values)
print(values[0].shape)
```

and the output that I got was this:

```
[array([[[ 0.05419183],
        [ 0.05344659],
        [ 0.16529882],
        [ 0.13316289],
        [ 0.08670449],
        [-0.08431631],
        [ 0.21874362],
        [-0.04441097],
        [-0.1314552 ],
        [ 0.16949281],
        [-0.2800545 ],
        [-0.10437775]],

       [[ 0.09547389],
        [ 0.15477252],
        [-0.16764301],
        [ 0.12441275],
        [ 0.02340332],
        [-0.10317421],
        [ 0.18521494],
        [-0.15572114],
        [ 0.19401571],
        [ 0.16722432],
        [-0.12812108],
        [-0.01085776]],

       [[ 0.11188135],
        [-0.2401814 ],
        [-0.22067368],
        [ 0.1589238 ],
        [-0.2589662 ],
        [ 0.06817111],
        [ 0.25940222],
        [-0.26351452],
        [ 0.0645991 ],
        [-0.1845657 ],
        [-0.12384695],
        [-0.09199122]],

       [[-0.2525922 ],
        [ 0.23261184],
        [ 0.09640783],
        [ 0.09529975],
        [-0.07000376],
        [-0.05982879],
        [ 0.22581965],
        [ 0.22685426],
        [ 0.16188478],
        [ 0.00062832],
        [-0.12596014],
        [ 0.23314512]],

       [[-0.21607567],
        [-0.28346273],
        [ 0.132777  ],
        [-0.03549922],
        [ 0.22499591],
        [-0.26649013],
        [-0.03834796],
        [ 0.20658016],
        [ 0.02062631],
        [-0.15602553],
        [ 0.07533735],
        [ 0.24847025]]], dtype=float32)]
(5, 12, 1)
```

The weights extracted have a shape which is basically a numpy array of 5 batches 12 rows and 1 column which makes sense and mathematically proves what the article says.

Questions:

1. So if I club all the values of 12 rows 1 column in all the 5 batches, then will that be my kernel??If no then how to visualize my kernel??
2. How to find the kernel having the highest weight associated with it for binary classification in Conv1d??

I am only a beginner in this. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.